# What is the formal way to determine the linkage of a `_Thread_local` identifier?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11, linkage, thread-local-storage

This is a 'language-lawyer' type question about a corner case in the C11 Standard.

The rules that determine the linkage of an identifier in a C program are spelled out in
clause 6.2.2 of the C11 Standard. In particular, 6.2.2(5) states that (emphasis mine):

> If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no storage-class specifier, its linkage
>     is determined exactly as if it were declared with the storage-class specifier `extern`. If
>     the declaration of an identifier for an **object** has **file scope** and **no storage-class specifier**,
>     its linkage is external.

In the case of a declaration such as `_Thread_local int a;` in a file scope, 6.2.2(5) above does not apply,
since `_Thread_local` **is** a storage specifier. None of the other provisions of 6.2.2 apply, either
(no `static` so (3) does not apply, not in block scope, is an object and not a parameter, so (6) is not applicable, etc.). So what
*should* the linkage of `a` be *according to the Standard*? Am I missing some other rules that determine the linkage in this case?

I understand that the intention is to make it have external linkage (which is how gcc treats this case) but how
does this follow from the Standard itself?

Note that is is perfectly ok to have a declaration like
`static _Thread_local int a; extern _Thread_local int a;` in which case 6.2.2 rules apply just fine making `a` have internal linkage (that `extern` notwithstanding).

Finally, the semantics of `_Thread_local` are not relevant here.

Comment: You could note that [C11 §6.7.1 Storage-class specifiers ¶3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.1p3) does not apply since the declaration is at file scope, not block scope.

Comment: In C99, §6.2.2 ¶5 says: _If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no storage-class specifier, its linkage
is determined exactly as if it were declared with the storage-class specifier `extern`. If
the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and no storage-class specifier,
its linkage is external._  That's essentially the same if not a verbatim copy.  I think, but  am not certain, that the paragraph applies as if the `_Thread_local` was not present.  It could perhaps be argued that there's a glitch here that would have been avoided if starting from scratch.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Completely agree about 6.7.1 and the (possible) glitch. Another curious case is `register` declarations of functions (which do not make any sense, of course): one has to put together 6.7.1(7) (prohibits storage specifiers other than `extern` for block level functions) and 6.9(2) (no register for file scope declarations) to derive that functions cannot be declared `register`. It works but I am not sure it was intended that the reason be so convoluted.

Comment: On functions, that's easy.  [C11 §6.9.1 Function definitions ¶4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.1p4) says: _The storage-class specifier, if any, in the declaration specifiers shall be either `extern` or `static`._

Comment: Definitions, yes, I was talking about declarations.

Comment: `_Thread_local` is the first storage-class specifier not to be mutually exclusive with all the others, and the first one to be added since C89; so I concur with Jonathan Leffler that this is an editorial mistake - they missed the interaction with the "no storage-class specifier" language.

Comment: Function declarations and `auto` and `register`: [C11 §6.9 External definitions ¶2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9p2): _The storage-class specifiers `auto` and `register` shall not appear in the declaration
specifiers in an external declaration._

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: 6.9(2) handles the external declarations (so file scope) but one still needs 6.7.1(7) for the block scope function declarations.

Answer (score 0):

As I read it, per C11 6.2.4p4, at file scope _Thread_local applies to the thread of main(), effectively moving them as static or extern references in the { } block of main(), rather than auto, and left implementation-defined how thread functions other than main() have access to them. I agree it appears to be a defect that it does not mention that the defining declaration of any object that is _Thread_local should be required to have static or extern as additional qualifier, not just 'may appear' as a referencing declaration, in 6.7.1p2.

Comment: It seems to be a consensus that this is a defect. One might argue that 'storage specifier' is a bit too wide a class, since `auto`, `extern`, and `static` have very different uses: the first one is to specify duration, the second one linkage, while the third one may do either. The question was about *linkage*, however, so 6.2.4 is not very relevant. Certainly functions other than `main` can access `_Thread_local` variables declared in file scope.